# Render path with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models, Carousel and Item, their relation is many to many.

In routes.rb:

```
resources :carousels do
  resources :items
end
```

I'm trying to render new items template with an enumerator param(type) in a modal in my carousel index.

Render code:

```
render new_carousel_item_path(caroulsel), type: "image"
```

But I'm having the following issue:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate at /carousels
Missing partial carousels/1/items/_new with {:locale=>[:"pt-BR"], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :slim, :coffee]}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say render rails will try to find partial.

Comment: or you can pass template

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pass parameter in render - rails 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283675/pass-parameter-in-render-rails-3)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this form

```
render template: "carousels/items/new", locals: {caroulsel: caroulsel, type: "image"}
```